# what is the difference between addClass and attr?

Tags: jquery

For adding a class we can use like the below

```
$('#x').addClass('test');
```

we can also do by the following way

```
$('#x').attr('class','test');
```

So I want to know are these both the ways same and there are some differences

Comment: addClass will just add a class, while attr will remove all classes and add the .test class alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example :**

```
<div id="x" class="a">
```

---

```
$('#x').addClass('test');
```

**Result:**

```
<div id="x" class="a test">
```

---

```
$('#x').attr('class','test');
```

**Result:**

```
<div id="x" class="test">
```

---

**But if you talking about perf. See this..**

http://jsperf.com/jquery-addclass-vs-attr-class-vs-prop-class/3

Answer (score 2):

`$('#x').attr('class','test');` will remove all existing class and set `test` as the only class...

where as `$('#x').addClass('test');` will add the class `test` to existing set of classes if it is already not present

```
<div id="x" class="some class"></div>
```

In the above markup `.addClass('test')` will result in `class="some class test"`, where as `.attr('class','test')` will create `class="test"`